# Unable to delete a folder from server 2012 R2

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, dfs

I had a replication enable a folder which was replicating data to a server 2012 r2 but i have disbale the replication but i'm unable to delete this folder or re-enable the replication.

We had a probelm the dfs replication on a folder which we disble it to remove any data from other site but now when I re-enable to dfs i get error "server(folder): Security cannot be set on the replicated folder. access is denined"

When I try to delete the folder from server 2012 R2 i get "You required permission from admin to mkae changes to this folder"

Please find the images

https://1drv.ms/f/s!At0UGnArT7e5nDVt3MPjYJvv3dZ1

UPDATE:
After delete the membership i'm now able to delete the data but i got new problem now. I cant delete the connection. When I delete the connection i get following error "Server to mainserver: The dfs replication connection object cannot be deleted. the user has insuffuient access reights."

Comment: Explain this replication. Replicating how? With what?

Comment: "It doesn't work" is not a helpful description of a problem. More details, please. Your question is unanswerable because you don't say what happens when you try to delete it or re-enable replication.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have Permissions into the folder.
Make sure in the security tab that your user has permissions.

---

[image: Share Security Permissions]

---

And also check the Shared tab permissions and make sure that your user is listed.

[image: Share Security Permissions]

---

Comment: I do have full admin rights and also I cant make changes to any security.

Comment: Take ownership of the folder. and then delete it
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753659%28v=ws.11%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: I have try it and still no luck

Comment: i have upload new image to show that I cant apply new permission or make changes to current permission. https://1drv.ms/i/s!At0UGnArT7e5nDooKig2kpn5wKon

Comment: as you can see i have full control. https://1drv.ms/i/s!At0UGnArT7e5nDtyMAPpXSsBkXRy

Comment: I see, in this case, you are getting the permissions from a parent folder (permissions are being taken using the inherence) So check the permissions on the parent folder, and also check is inherence is enable or disable.

Comment: the image is for parent folder. I'm trring to delete the parent folder which i cant because it saying i dont have permission.

Comment: this is only happening on server 2012 r2 server but 2008 r2 its all ok.

Comment: Where is located the "parent folder" E:\Folder\x86 what I mean is look for the permissions in "folder" and if it's not there you need to look in the Drive E: permissions from My Pc.

Comment: please see my update

Comment: Check permissions in the delegates:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/893419c6-a9b5-4b1d-a7b4-377607426b1b/unable-to-delete-dfs-replication-group?forum=winserverfiles (Use MedicalS CSG) answer a bit lower from the middle of the page

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is still in use by someone.

Try to disconnect all clients (reboot machine etc..) and set owner and permissions as described in other answers.

Comment: restart the server and also disable to dfs service

Comment: You deleted all data from other side and now you cannot start service because it can't set permission on other side. Try to restore data, enable service, set permissions on both and then try to update folders

Comment: the problme i cant delete the data, I cant do anything with replicated folder on server 2012 r2

Answer (score 0):

After deleteing the membership from dfs management i was able to delete the files from server 2012 r2

Comment: Wait...so were you trying to delete the DFSRPrivate folder prior to removing the server from the DFS rep group membership?